# cannot connect to report server in SSRS for configuration

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, windows-10

I need some help installing SSRS. I am following this link’s instructions. I have installed the report server but am receiving this error when trying to connect to configure it in the Report Server Configuration Manager. I don’t quite understand the error message. Any ideas? Thanks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040208)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WmiProviders.GetInstance(String machineName, String instanceName, RSWmiNamespaces rsNamespace, ConnectionOptions connOptions, ObjectGetOptions getOptions, String version)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WmiProviders.GetReportServerAdmin(String machineName, String instanceName, ConnectionOptions connOptions, ObjectGetOptions getOptions, String version)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WmiProviders.GetReportServerAdmin(String machineName, String instanceName, ConnectionOptions connOptions, ObjectGetOptions getOptions)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSInstances.GetReportServerAdmin(RSInstance rsinstance)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.ConfigurationManager.ChangeMachine()
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.ConfigurationManager.LaunchDialog()
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.ConfigurationManager.OnActivated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.set_Active(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmActivate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
RSConfigTool
    Assembly Version: 15.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 15.0.1102.675
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services/Shared%20Tools/RSConfigTool.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4150.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.4110.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
   Win32 Version: 4.8.4180.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_B
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
CrowdStrike.Sensor.ScriptControl
    Assembly Version: 5.31.11304.0
    Win32 Version: 5.31.11304.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/System32/CrowdStrike.Sensor.ScriptControl11304.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.8.3761.0 built by: NET48REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Editions
    Assembly Version: 2019.11.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2019.11.7.2
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services/Shared%20Tools/Microsoft.ReportingServices.Editions.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: How are you trying to connect? What is the error message you're seeing?

Comment: When SSRS doesn't install/startup nicely, it puts different error messages in different places/logs.  For instance: NT Event logs (application, or system), the RSConfig tool, log files in `C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services/*`.  Which one showed you this error message?

Comment: @tgolisch if i understand the RSConfig tool showed this message when i attempted to connect to the Report Server to configure it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received other errors that narrowed down the issue. I needed windows admin privileges to install/config SSRS.

[image]